# Comportamento estranho em BD - Demasiados registos

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

O problema é que isto devolve-me 8 registos enquanto que na base de dados apenas estão 2. Ou seja 4 para cada 1. Não consigo compreender porque.
(Se quiserem editem o titulo da pergunta)

Tenho esta BD:

[image: Diagrama da base de dados.]

E tenho este select:

```
select alunos.numero,faltas_licao.tipo 

from turma,alunos,disciplinas,licao,faltas_licao 

where faltas_licao.aluno_id = alunos.id_aluno 

and licao.id_turma = turma.id_turma 

and faltas_licao.id_disciplina = licao.id_disciplina 

and licao.id_disciplina = disciplinas.id_disciplina 

and faltas_licao.licao = '" & currentlicao & "' 

and disciplinas.nome = '" & F_Topo.CB_Disciplina.SelectedItem.ToString & "' 

and turma.nome = '" & F_Topo.CB_Turma.SelectedItem.ToString & "' 

and alunos.Numero = '" & aluno & "'"
```

Aqui esta o codigo "todo":

```
 Dim con3 As New SqlConnection(cs)
            Dim currentlicao As Integer = get_licao()
            'MsgBox("current: " & currentlicao)
            Using con3
                Dim aluno As Integer = linha.Index

                Dim sql As String = "select alunos.numero,faltas_licao.tipo from turma,alunos,disciplinas,licao,faltas_licao where faltas_licao.aluno_id = alunos.id_aluno and licao.id_turma = turma.id_turma and faltas_licao.id_disciplina = licao.id_disciplina and licao.id_disciplina = disciplinas.id_disciplina and faltas_licao.licao = '" & currentlicao & "' and disciplinas.nome = '" & F_Topo.CB_Disciplina.SelectedItem.ToString & "' and turma.nome = '" & F_Topo.CB_Turma.SelectedItem.ToString & "' and alunos.Numero = '" & aluno & "'"
                'MsgBox(sql)
                Dim sqlCom As New SqlCommand(sql, con3)
                con3.Open()
                Dim dr3 As SqlDataReader = sqlCom.ExecuteReader()

                Dim miau As Integer = 0


                If dr3.HasRows Then
                    While dr3.Read()
                        miau = miau + 1
                        'F_Principal.DataGridView2.Rows.Add(F_Principal.DataGridView2.RowCount + 1, dr3.Item(0))
                        MsgBox(miau)
                        MsgBox("ID: " & dr3.Item(0) & "TIPO:" & dr3.Item(1))
                    End While
                Else
                    ' Aqui faça o que quiser caso não tenha linha '
                End If
                dr3.Close()
```

Dados na base de dados:

[image: Dados]

Não entendo como é que ele me devolve quatro registos(alias 8 registos, sendo 4 repetidos).

Alguém com experiência em base de dados me consegue detectar o erro?

---

EDIT:

Erro:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The objects "faltas_licao" and "faltas_licao" in the FROM clause have the same exposed names. Use correlation names to distinguish them.
>      em System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>      em System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>      em System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>      em System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
>      em System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
>      em System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
>      em System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
>      em System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
>      em System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
>      em System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
>      em System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
>      em System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
>      em Trabalho_mod_16.F_Contentor.get_faltas() em C:\Users\AlunoP\Desktop\Trabalho modulo 16\Trabalho mod 16\Trabalho mod 16\F_Contentor.vb:line 163
>   ClientConnectionId:03d47535-a3d9-4723-b704-2649901d693e
>   Error Number:1013,State:1,Class:16

Comment: Sua query está errada. Procure utilizar algum INNER JOIN.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=468_48aSz68 - Vou utilizar isto como referencia.

Comment: E obrigado :)...

Comment: @gmsantos, substituir um JOIN inplicito por um explicito não vai corrigir a consulta e muito menos melhorar o desempenho, o unico ganho aqui seria de legibilidade.

Comment: @lemario, poderia dizer qual é a intenção da consulta? gostaria de pegar o total de faltas dos alunos? seja por aluno ou turma? em todo caso, te aconselho a não montar a sua consulta concatenando strings, parametrize a mesma.

Comment: @TobyMosque O que eu pretendo fazer é para determinada Tuma,disciplina,licao e aluno receber o tipo de falta, para depois colocar numa tabela as faltas para cada aluno.

Answer (score 2):

Você deve fazer a união das tabelas usando `JOINS` e não pelo `WHERE`

os 5 principais tipos de JOIN são :

**INNER JOIN**

Retorna uma linha pra cada ocorrência de determinada relação entre 2 tabelas

exemplo : `select tabela1.* , tabela2.* from tabela1 inner join tabela2 ON tabela1.id = tabela2.fk_tabela1`

**LEFT JOIN**

Independente da relação ser atendida , retorna todas as linhas da tabela1 . Caso a relação seja atendida tambem retorna os dados da tabela2 , caso contrário , os dados da tabela1 sao preenchidos e o da tabela2 recebem NULL

exemplo : `select tabela1.* , tabela2.* from tabela1 left join tabela2 ON tabela1.id = tabela2.fk_tabela1`

**RIGHT JOIN**

Independente da relação ser atendida , retorna todas as linhas da tabela2 . Caso a relação seja atendida também retorna os dados da tabela1 , caso contrário , os dados da tabela2 sao preenchidos e o da tabela1 recebem NULL

exemplo : `select tabela1.* , tabela2.* from tabela1 right join tabela2 ON tabela1.id = tabela2.fk_tabela1`

**FULL JOIN**

Retorna as relações atendidas e tanto as ocorrencias da tabela 1 sem relação com a tabela 2 , quanto as ocorrencias da tabela 2 sem relação com a tabela 1

exemplo : `select tabela1.* , tabela2.* from tabela1 full join tabela2 ON tabela1.id = tabela2.fk_tabela1`

**CROSS JOIN**

Cada linha da tabela 1 é retornada combinada com cada linha da tabela 2

exemplo : `select tabela1.* , tabela2.* from tabela1 cross join tabela2`

Sua query deve funcionar do jeito que está simplesmente adicionando `DISTINCT` na frente do `SELECT`

Mas acredito que a query ideal é próxima do seguinte

`select distinct alunos.numero,faltas_licao.tipo from alunos 
    left join faltas_licao on faltas_licao.aluno_id = alunos.id_aluno 
    left join turma on alunos.id_turma = turma.id_turma 
    left join licao on licao.id_turma = turma.id_turma 
    left join faltas_licao on faltas_licao.id_disciplina = licao.id_disciplina 
    left join disciplinas on licao.id_disciplina = disciplinas.id_disciplina 
    where faltas_licao.licao = '" & currentlicao & "' 
    and disciplinas.nome = '" & F_Topo.CB_Disciplina.SelectedItem.ToString & "' 
    and turma.nome = '" & F_Topo.CB_Turma.SelectedItem.ToString & "' 
    and alunos.Numero = '" & aluno & "'"`

E embora sua tabela só tenha 4 registros , ela retorna mais resultados porque sua query realiza as avaliações do `WHERE` pra cada uma das tabelas que vc incluiu no `FROM`, reavaliando o mesmo dado muitas vezes ,  e dessa forma se não acrescentar `DISTINCT`na frente do `SELECT`, ela vai retornar uma linha pra cada comparação que for atendida , independente de ja ter sido retornada antes .

Comment: Como complemento a "teoria" dos `JOINS`, [esse resposta que explica ilustradamente e muito bem cada uma das variações de `JOINS`](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/6448/2998).

Comment: +1 pelos joins.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Introduzi o seu código e não funciona. Se puser o distinct no meu, já faz o que quero. Quais sao os beneficios de usar o left join em vez de usar apenas o distinct? 

Pus o erro na pergunta.

Comment: As principais vantagens que vejo são 1) Join é o padrão pra junção de tabelas e difícilmente vc vai ver código usando o WHERE pra fazer isso . 2) Ganho em flexibilidade e facilidade pra ler e escrever as querys . 3)  Embora o @TobyMosque tenha dito que ambas tem o mesmo plano de exec , acredito que a única maneira pra que isso seja possível é com o compilador entendendo que ambas as querys são equivalentes mas dessa maneira , você fica limitado ao entendimento do compilador e não pode forçar um plano de exec diferente . ex: vc pode foçar "merge,loop... join" , e não "merge,loop... where"

Answer (score 2):

Apesar de discordar da explicação sobre os `JOIN`s dada pelo @DiegoValadares, pois se analisar o plano de execução ao utilizar INNER JOIN e WHERE, ocê verá que ambos possuem o mesmo plano de execução.

sintaticamente prefiro o `JOIN`, pois este deixa explicito a minha intenção em ligar as tabelas, usaria o WHERE apenas se estive-se lidando com algum banco de dados antigo, daqueles que usam `ANSI-89`, afinal o JOIN não é uma opção aqui.

Mas o seu problema aqui é a ligação da tabela `licao` com `faltas_licao`, para fazer esta ligação de forma apropriada, você deve comparar todas as colunas que compoem a chave primaria de `licao`, então a sua consulta ficaria assim:

```
select 
    alunos.numero,
    faltas_licao.tipo 
from licao
join turma on licao.id_turma = turma.id_turma 
join disciplinas on licao.id_disciplina = disciplinas.id_disciplina 
join faltas_licao on 
    licao.id_turma = faltas_licao.id_turma and
    licao.id_disciplina = faltas_licao.id_disciplina and    
    licao.licao = faltas_licao.licao
join alunos on faltas_licao.aluno_id = alunos.id_aluno 
where 
    faltas_licao.licao = @licao and
    disciplinas.nome = @disciplina and
    turma.nome = @turma and
    alunos.Numero = @aluno
```

outro ponto, evite concatenar strings na hora de montar a sua consulta, ao invés disto parametrize a sua consulta.

```
Dim sql As String = "" & _
    "select" & vbCrLf & _
    "   alunos.numero," & vbCrLf & _
    "   faltas_licao.tipo" & vbCrLf & _ 
    "from licao" & vbCrLf & _
    "join turma on licao.id_turma = turma.id_turma" & vbCrLf & _ 
    "join disciplinas on licao.id_disciplina = disciplinas.id_disciplina" & vbCrLf & _
    "join faltas_licao on" & vbCrLf & _ 
    "   licao.id_turma = faltas_licao.id_turma and" & vbCrLf & _
    "   licao.id_disciplina = faltas_licao.id_disciplina and" & vbCrLf & _  
    "   licao.licao = faltas_licao.licao" & vbCrLf & _
    "join alunos on faltas_licao.aluno_id = alunos.id_aluno" & vbCrLf & _ 
    "where" & vbCrLf & _ 
    "   faltas_licao.licao = @licao and" & vbCrLf & _
    "   disciplinas.nome = @disciplina and" & vbCrLf & _
    "   turma.nome = @turma and" & vbCrLf & _
    "   alunos.Numero = @aluno"

Dim sqlCom As New SqlCommand(sql, con3)
sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@licao", currentlicao)
sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@disciplina", F_Topo.CB_Disciplina.SelectedItem.ToString)
sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@turma", F_Topo.CB_Turma.SelectedItem.ToString)
sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aluno", aluno)
```

Uma ultima dica, seria mover esta consulta para um `Resource`, para isto, salve o seu script como um arquivo `*.sql` e adicione o mesmo como Resource do seu projeto.

Comment: Tem certeza que ambas possuem o mesmo plano de execução ? Realmente não sabia sobre isso , imaginei que não pois a não ser que vc declare explicitamente que tipo de join ( loop , merge ou hash)  ele tenta realizar o que ele entende que vai gerar o melhor plano de execução , e também se vc não forçar a ordem dos joins , o bd faz a ordem das junções de acordo com o que " entende " que vai gerar o melhor plano de execução

Comment: Diego, o tipo do Join vai influenciar no plano de execução, porém neste caso especifico ele está usando um join implicito, como era especificado no `ANSI SQL-89`, vale lembrar que o os operadores `*=`, `=*`, `*=*`, que são respectivamente o `LEFT JOIN`, o `RIGHT JOIN` e o `FULL JOIN` foram descotinuados.

Comment: @DiegoValadares, mas não me entenda mal, eu defendo o uso do JOIN explicito em detrimento do JOIN implicito, apesar de não haver um ganho de desempenho, existe um ganho enorme de legibilidade. se quiser ler mais a respeito, leia a introdução do seguinte link: [SQL SERVER – What is the Difference Between An INNER JOIN and WHERE Clause](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/10/13/sql-server-what-is-the-difference-between-an-inner-join-and-where-clause/)

Comment: pois é , eu pesquisei se um join é mais rápido que um where e no stack em inglês a melhor resposta é a seguinte : "Teoricamente,não, não deve ser nem um pouco mais rápido. O otimizador de queries deve ser capaz de gerar planos de execução indÊnticos para ambos. No entando, Alguns sistemas de BD podem gerar planos de execução melhores pra um deles(dificilmente vai acontecer para queries simples e sim para as complexas). Você deve testar as 2 e ver (No seu sistema de BD)."  http://stackoverflow.com/a/1129938

Comment: @DiegoValadares, a resposta em questão tem um escopo mais amplo, no exemplo acima temos um SGBD especifico, no caso o Sql-Server.

Comment: Ele sempre gera o mesmo plano de execução independente da complexidade da query ? @TobyMosque

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35284/discussion-between-diego-valadares-and-tobymosque).